# Need text converter (want to change format)

Tags: batch-file

I have a file with text in this format:

```
Name1:Pw1
Name2:Pw2

...
```

And I want to convert in to this format:

```
{
  "AuthType": "ptc",
  "GoogleUsername": "null",
  "GooglePassword": "null",
  "PtcUsername": "",
  "PtcPassword": ""
}
```

The `name1` should be filled in `PtcUsername` and the `Pw1` in `PtcPassword` and so on!

Comment: Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This community will not just provide answers. Please let us know what you have tried and at which part of the process you find trouble. Then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

as an starting point, try

```
@echo off

set "output=formatted.txt"
set "data_file=source.txt"

copy NUL "%output%">NUL & rem create an empty file for output data

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (%data_file%) do (
  (
    echo/{
    echo/  "AuthType": "ptc",
    echo/  "GoogleUsername": "null",
    echo/  "GooglePassword": "null",
    echo/  "PtcUsername": "%%a",
    echo/  "PtcPassword": "%%b"
    echo/}
  )>>"%output%"
)

exit/B
```